# Function behaviour depending on whether a trait is implemented

Tags: rust

Given a situation like this one :

```
trait Basic {
    // Some functions
}

trait Derived : Basic {
    // some other functions
}

fn do_someting<T : Basic>(target: &mut T) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Is it possible to have the `do_something` function behave differently depending on whether `target` implements the trait `Derived` or not (the information being known at compilation time) ?

I guess something similar could be achieved in C++ using template specialization, but I don't see a Rust equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is not currently possible. Defining `fn do_something<T : Derived>` alongside your existing function leads to compilation error:

```
error: duplicate definition of value `do_someting`
```

because both versions can be used for Basic.

There are some proposals to allow explicit bounds like `<T: Basic + !Derived>` that will allow you to resolve this conflict.

But I personally hope that impl overloading/specialization will be possible some day after 1.0 version is released.